# Something has installed Jetty and starts on boot-up

Tags: macos, jetty, homebrew

After a macOS High Sierra (10.13.6) update, which required a reboot, I found that Jetty 9.4.z-SNAPSHOT was running on port 8080.

As I use JBoss WildFly 13.0.0.Final I use Undertow as my web server and I have not intentionally installed Jetty. If I 'locate' Jetty it shows in the following directories (see quoted text at end).

I did install Solr 6.x using brew and update it regularly. But it has never 'interfered' with JBoss WildFly before, even after reboots.

I did not inadvertently install Jetty with Homebrew as:

> brew info jetty jetty: stable 9.4.11.v20180605 Java servlet engine and
>   webserver https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/ Not installed

Can I just delete 'Jetty' and how can I see how/where Jetty is started from. Not shown in the macOS start-up?

locate */jetty*

```
MacBook-Pro:/ NOTiFY$  locate */jetty*
/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA 2018.2 EAP.app/Contents/plugins/Jetty/lib/jettyIntegration.jar
/Users/NOTiFY/.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-4.8.1-all/6fmj4nezasjg1b7kkmy10xgo2/gradle-4.8.1/docs/userguide/img/jettyPluginTasks.png
/Users/NOTiFY/.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-4.8.1-all/6fmj4nezasjg1b7kkmy10xgo2/gradle-4.8.1/docs/userguide/jetty_plugin.html
/Users/NOTiFY/.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-4.9-all/491wbe0x5d54n9cojs2p0zv90/gradle-4.9/docs/userguide/img/jettyPluginTasks.png
/Users/NOTiFY/.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-4.9-all/491wbe0x5d54n9cojs2p0zv90/gradle-4.9/docs/userguide/jetty_plugin.html
/Users/NOTiFY/apache-activemq-5.14.0/conf/jetty-realm.properties
/Users/NOTiFY/apache-activemq-5.14.0/conf/jetty.xml
/Users/NOTiFY/apache-activemq-5.14.0/examples/conf/jetty-demo.xml
/Users/NOTiFY/apache-activemq-5.14.0/lib/web/jetty-all-9.2.13.v20150730.jar
/Users/NOTiFY/macports/var/macports/sources/rsync.macports.org/release/tarballs/ports/www/jetty
/Users/NOTiFY/macports/var/macports/sources/rsync.macports.org/release/tarballs/ports/www/jetty/Portfile
/usr/local/Cellar/solr/7.4.0/libexec/licenses/jetty-6.1.26.jar.sha1
/usr/local/Cellar/solr/7.4.0/libexec/licenses/jetty-LICENSE-ASL.txt
/usr/local/Cellar/solr/7.4.0/libexec/licenses/jetty-NOTICE.txt
/usr/local/Cellar/solr/7.4.0/libexec/licenses/jetty-continuation-9.4.10.v20180503.jar.sha1
/usr/local/Cellar/solr/7.4.0/libexec/licenses/jetty-deploy-9.4.10.v20180503.jar.sha1
/usr/local/Cellar/solr/7.4.0/libexec/licenses/jetty-http-9.4.10.v20180503.jar.sha1
/usr/local/Cellar/solr/7.4.0/libexec/licenses/jetty-io-9.4.10.v20180503.jar.sha1
/usr/local/Cellar/solr/7.4.0/libexec/licenses/jetty-jmx-9.4.10.v20180503.jar.sha1
/usr/local/Cellar/solr/7.4.0/libexec/licenses/jetty-rewrite-9.4.10.v20180503.jar.sha1
/usr/local/Cellar/solr/7.4.0/libexec/licenses/jetty-security-9.4.10.v20180503.jar.sha1
/usr/local/Cellar/solr/7.4.0/libexec/licenses/jetty-server-9.4.10.v20180503.jar.sha1
/usr/local/Cellar/solr/7.4.0/libexec/licenses/jetty-servlet-9.4.10.v20180503.jar.sha1
/usr/local/Cellar/solr/7.4.0/libexec/licenses/jetty-servlets-9.4.10.v20180503.jar.sha1
/usr/local/Cellar/solr/7.4.0/libexec/licenses/jetty-sslengine-6.1.26.jar.sha1
/usr/local/Cellar/solr/7.4.0/libexec/licenses/jetty-util-6.1.26.jar.sha1
/usr/local/Cellar/solr/7.4.0/libexec/licenses/jetty-util-9.4.10.v20180503.jar.sha1
/usr/local/Cellar/solr/7.4.0/libexec/licenses/jetty-webapp-9.4.10.v20180503.jar.sha1
/usr/local/Cellar/solr/7.4.0/libexec/licenses/jetty-xml-9.4.10.v20180503.jar.sha1
/usr/local/Cellar/solr/7.4.0/server/etc/jetty-http.xml
/usr/local/Cellar/solr/7.4.0/server/etc/jetty-https.xml
/usr/local/Cellar/solr/7.4.0/server/etc/jetty-ssl.xml
/usr/local/Cellar/solr/7.4.0/server/etc/jetty.xml
/usr/local/Cellar/solr/7.4.0/server/lib/jetty-continuation-9.4.10.v20180503.jar
/usr/local/Cellar/solr/7.4.0/server/lib/jetty-deploy-9.4.10.v20180503.jar
/usr/local/Cellar/solr/7.4.0/server/lib/jetty-http-9.4.10.v20180503.jar
/usr/local/Cellar/solr/7.4.0/server/lib/jetty-io-9.4.10.v20180503.jar
/usr/local/Cellar/solr/7.4.0/server/lib/jetty-jmx-9.4.10.v20180503.jar
/usr/local/Cellar/solr/7.4.0/server/lib/jetty-rewrite-9.4.10.v20180503.jar
/usr/local/Cellar/solr/7.4.0/server/lib/jetty-security-9.4.10.v20180503.jar
/usr/local/Cellar/solr/7.4.0/server/lib/jetty-server-9.4.10.v20180503.jar
/usr/local/Cellar/solr/7.4.0/server/lib/jetty-servlet-9.4.10.v20180503.jar
/usr/local/Cellar/solr/7.4.0/server/lib/jetty-servlets-9.4.10.v20180503.jar
/usr/local/Cellar/solr/7.4.0/server/lib/jetty-util-9.4.10.v20180503.jar
/usr/local/Cellar/solr/7.4.0/server/lib/jetty-webapp-9.4.10.v20180503.jar
/usr/local/Cellar/solr/7.4.0/server/lib/jetty-xml-9.4.10.v20180503.jar
/usr/local/Cellar/solr/7.4.0/server/resources/jetty-logging.properties
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core/Formula/jetty-runner.rb
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core/Formula/jetty.rb
/usr/local/opt/libexec/licenses/jetty-6.1.26.jar.sha1
/usr/local/opt/libexec/licenses/jetty-LICENSE-ASL.txt
/usr/local/opt/libexec/licenses/jetty-NOTICE.txt
/usr/local/opt/libexec/licenses/jetty-continuation-9.4.10.v20180503.jar.sha1
/usr/local/opt/libexec/licenses/jetty-deploy-9.4.10.v20180503.jar.sha1
/usr/local/opt/libexec/licenses/jetty-http-9.4.10.v20180503.jar.sha1
/usr/local/opt/libexec/licenses/jetty-io-9.4.10.v20180503.jar.sha1
/usr/local/opt/libexec/licenses/jetty-jmx-9.4.10.v20180503.jar.sha1
/usr/local/opt/libexec/licenses/jetty-rewrite-9.4.10.v20180503.jar.sha1
/usr/local/opt/libexec/licenses/jetty-security-9.4.10.v20180503.jar.sha1
/usr/local/opt/libexec/licenses/jetty-server-9.4.10.v20180503.jar.sha1
/usr/local/opt/libexec/licenses/jetty-servlet-9.4.10.v20180503.jar.sha1
/usr/local/opt/libexec/licenses/jetty-servlets-9.4.10.v20180503.jar.sha1
/usr/local/opt/libexec/licenses/jetty-sslengine-6.1.26.jar.sha1
/usr/local/opt/libexec/licenses/jetty-util-6.1.26.jar.sha1
/usr/local/opt/libexec/licenses/jetty-util-9.4.10.v20180503.jar.sha1
/usr/local/opt/libexec/licenses/jetty-webapp-9.4.10.v20180503.jar.sha1
/usr/local/opt/libexec/licenses/jetty-xml-9.4.10.v20180503.jar.sha1
/usr/local/opt/server/etc/jetty-http.xml
/usr/local/opt/server/etc/jetty-https.xml
/usr/local/opt/server/etc/jetty-ssl.xml
/usr/local/opt/server/etc/jetty.xml
/usr/local/opt/server/lib/jetty-continuation-9.4.10.v20180503.jar
/usr/local/opt/server/lib/jetty-deploy-9.4.10.v20180503.jar
/usr/local/opt/server/lib/jetty-http-9.4.10.v20180503.jar
/usr/local/opt/server/lib/jetty-io-9.4.10.v20180503.jar
/usr/local/opt/server/lib/jetty-jmx-9.4.10.v20180503.jar
/usr/local/opt/server/lib/jetty-rewrite-9.4.10.v20180503.jar
/usr/local/opt/server/lib/jetty-security-9.4.10.v20180503.jar
/usr/local/opt/server/lib/jetty-server-9.4.10.v20180503.jar
/usr/local/opt/server/lib/jetty-servlet-9.4.10.v20180503.jar
/usr/local/opt/server/lib/jetty-servlets-9.4.10.v20180503.jar
/usr/local/opt/server/lib/jetty-util-9.4.10.v20180503.jar
/usr/local/opt/server/lib/jetty-webapp-9.4.10.v20180503.jar
/usr/local/opt/server/lib/jetty-xml-9.4.10.v20180503.jar
/usr/local/opt/server/resources/jetty-logging.properties
```

Answer (score 1):

Solr comes with an embedded-jetty (that's how it works).

See https://wiki.apache.org/solr/WhyNoWar for details on why Solr went this way.

Comment: But I haven't started Solr, If I run 'solr status' it says "No Solr nodes are running."